# Javascript/jQuery doesn't work with my html and css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I learned about jQuery but when I try it out and launch the html, it doesn't work, here's my code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/redorgreen.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="blok1">test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

the css (redorgreen.css):

```
.blok1
{
    background: url(../img/fblogo.png);
    background-size: cover; 
    }
```

and finally the javascript (test.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.blok1').remove();
    });
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong.. if someone could help me out on this one? Thanks!

Comment: load test.js after loading jQuery. :)

Comment: You getting blank output, right?

Comment: how _it doesn't work_? any error in console or not remove?

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks for the quick answer! :) (I had to put the js file behind the jQuery)

Comment: Now please learn how to debug javascript/jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change HTML in this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/test.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/redorgreen.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="blok1">test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you need to include script afeter loading JQuery